# Find two occurrences in column and format text

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

EXCEL 2010 VBA Code request

I have a workbook that has multiple sheets with similar data in each sheet.  The first cell (A1) contains the TITLE of each sheet, and a group of information that needs to be captured (G4:K?)(ranging from 32-65 rows).  Both the TITLE and grouped data is copied and pasted (values only) into a separate “Summary” sheet.  This happen for all sheets in the workbook.  I have this code, and it works.
Okay, so here’s where I am stuck:

In column A, I need the first instance of each TITLE to be **YELLOW background with RED BOLD text**.
Then the next instance (2nd) of the same TITLE to be **YELLOW background with BLACK BOLD text**. Please see Photo link below.

[Excel Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FT8C.png)
[image: Excel Problem]

I think this can be done via an array, but I don’t enough about arrays to tackle it.  Right now, it is all done manually (not good!!!)

This data formatting needs to change every time the sheet is updated (whether through filtering or data input changes).

Answer (score 0):

Please select the relevant column (assumed to be A) HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select yellow fill, bold, red font, OK, OK.

Then repeat for yellow/bold/back with:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=2
```

Comment: Pnuts, thanks for the simple solution!  I thought it was going to be a hard!  

So I tried the conditional formatting and it worked...as long as my data was NOT filtered.  Once I placed a filter on it, then the YELLOW hi-lighting went away (filtered out).

Is there a way that the Conditional Formatting can apply based on the filtered data?

Thanks again Pnuts for your solution!

Comment: Thanks anyways, pnuts.  My alternative solution is to start non-essential  data so the Conditional Filter shows the right info.

I've heard of having code automatically run when the sheet is activated.  I may go that route.


Thanks again!!!